# URL routing: do I need it, and why?

Tags: url, routes

While easy enough to find technical, technology-dependent descriptions of URL routing, it's surprisingly difficult to find a coherent summary of the various use cases (situations in which it might be required). I need to know under what hypothetical circumstances I am likely to need routing.

Some of those deriving from dynamic URL usage are outlined [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewrite_engine#Usage), but it seems unlikely that this list is exhaustive.

I'd be glad if someone could **list** these separately for static and dynamic URLs -including, where applicable, any more or less imposed by external tools and services.

If you find yourself talking in terms of HTTP actions such as GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE or equivalents, to my mind you're already going too deep.

As far as I can make out, this question was too stupid to be asked by anyone else. :-)

Tks..

Answer (score 0):

Yes you do need routing, routing can be an excellent way to get users to be able to effectively share a resource and find direct routes to it.

URL routes are basically GET requests sent by the browser to the web application, so theoretically you can do just as well with POST requests (i.e. without URLs), however for the reason mentioned above and also as a best practice (supported by most modern web frameworks) it's best that you use proper URLs, POST requests are probably just fine too - but i would suggest to use them when obfuscation of some parts of the web resources from the end user is required.

Comment: Thanks Mercy. While you're at it, could you also take a crack at answering the question? ;-)

Comment: i don't think i understand your question than, i believe i answered the title, however are you looking for a list of where routing in url is useful? i can't list it, but i tried to give you an idea - since the way you use URLs in your application is decided a lot based on the framework/platform you use, unless you design from scratch.